# which operation should take first

Tags: matlab

I am doing my matlab work, question is

**Shearing of 0.8 on x-axis, followed by a 45° (cc) rotation**

if my point is `[X] = [x;y]`

So what order should I take first, means if shearing matrix is `[S]` and rotation matrix is `[R]`, So would I do

`[Result] = [S] X [R] X [X]`

or I need to do like this

`[Result] = [R] X [S] X [X]`

Comment: Matrix operations read right to left like Arabic. So [S] X [R] is rotate first, shear after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said you are doing a matrix multiplication of [S] and [R]. As you know matrix multiplication do NOT commute, i.e. you can't switch positions.

**Correct**

```
[Result] = [R] x [S] x [x]
```

**Wrong**

```
[Result] = [S] x [R] x [x]
```